# MySQL search for "$" (dollar sign) fails?

Tags: mysql, special-characters

Been asked to find dollar values across a large body of text. Can a search be performed on the dollar sign? If so, any examples/guidance would be most appreciated. Current query...

```
select * from concept where concept_description like '%$%';
```

Comment: yes, no returns but when I eye-balled snippets of the text I saw a couple of dollar values.

Comment: There is no special meaning of `$` in a LIKE (or a SQL string literal). Unless the client sending the query is doing something funny with `$` - eeps! - I would imagine that the data and perceptions are not aligning ..

Comment: @user1753646 Try juergen's query and compare the results. They should be the same.

Comment: @juergen thanks for the query but zero returns. I knew this was going to be ugly...legacy data.

Comment: It should work. Must be something else. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c34b9/1

Comment: @juergen thanks for the query but zero returns. I knew this was going to be ugly...legacy data.

Comment: @user1753646 Then I suspect - it's not *really* `$`s or the collation is all entirely broken in every sense of broken :) I've also "assumed" that the correct table/column are used in the query .. do queries involving "normal characters" work?

Comment: @pst correct table/column name.

Comment: @pst queries involving "normal characters" do work

Comment: How are you executing the query? It's possible your language is doing string interpolation on this if you're not careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queries given will select the rows where `concept_description` contains a `$`, but I assume that you want to actually pull out the dollar amounts? If there's only ever just one dollar amount in a field it can be pulled out using

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(
    concept_description,
    LOCATE('$', concept_description),
    LOCATE(' ', concept_description, LOCATE('$', concept_description)) - LOCATE('$', concept_description)
)
FROM table
WHERE LOCATE('$', concept_description) > 0
```

This assume that the dollar amount is always followed by a space, and might need some fudging on the indexes. It's probably best to pull the full field out with a simple query, then use regular expressions to grab any dollar values.

Comment: thanks for the code but no initial returns. I'll play with the code a little and let you know the outcome.

Comment: Besides having the arguments to [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) mixed up (the needle comes *first*), why not just use `LIKE`?

Comment: @pst I think I may have figured this out using a regular experessions but need a devils advocate `select * from concept where concept_description rlike '\\$';`

Comment: Note: all of the `LOCATE()`s in my post had their arguments backwards. I've fixed them.

The `RLIKE` you've given seems to work, also it seems to be faster than `LOCATE()`.

Comment: @Sammitch Ran the code you fixed up and it worked nicely, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use `LOCATE` to see if the col value contains the `$` e.g.

```
   SELECT * FROM concept WHERE LOCATE('$', concept_description) > 0;
```