# mysql LIKE search doesn't work for text with space

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query for my cms, I use it to find posts based on provided search query by user:

```
"SELECT post_content FROM c_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%$s%' OR post_title LIKE '%$s%' OR post_description LIKE '%$s%' OR link_title LIKE '%$s%' OR tags LIKE '%$s%' AND post_status <> 'Initialized'";
```

It works fine when query `$s` is a word like '**something**' but it doesn't return anything if `$s` includes space anywhere like '**something else**' or **' something'**. I need to search for exact word. so I can't trim the space. how do deal with this? (because of performance concerns, I decided not to use FULLTEXT)

Comment: As far as I can tell, it should work.  Have you tried to print out your variable to see if it still contains the spaces in the string?

Comment: @LoganHasbrouck are you sure? Because it was my understanding that LIKE (in that form) can only handle one word...

Comment: I have just tested it both directly with raw sql and my own search function.  The variable works just as expected.  Raw: `select description from animes where description like '%e died%';` and laravel - toSql(): `select * from 'animes' where ('description' like ? or 'name' like ?)`.  Both returned the exact same thing when searching 'e died'.

Comment: `LIKE` should definitely handle spaces correctly, the special characters are `%` and `_` (escape with backslash). You should get better performance with `FULLTEXT` what were your concerns?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your code, I think you may be having a similar issue I used to have with my own site: the order of execution of 'AND's and 'OR's.  Here are a few links that may be of assistance.

[SQL Server ANDs and ORs precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094612/sql-server-ands-and-ors-precedence)

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm

Try this using a parenthesis:

```
SELECT post_content 
FROM c_posts 
WHERE (post_content LIKE '%$s%' OR post_title LIKE '%$s%' OR post_description LIKE '%$s%' OR link_title LIKE '%$s%' OR tags LIKE '%$s%') 
AND post_status <> 'Initialized'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your query:

1) The $ sign is managed in a particular way, look at this post for more answers: [MySQL search for "$" (dollar sign) fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035906/mysql-search-for-dollar-sign-fails)

2) You should enclose the ORs using parenthesis

```
SELECT post_content FROM c_posts WHERE 
  (post_content LIKE '%$s%' 
    OR post_title LIKE '%$s%' 
    OR post_description LIKE '%$s%' 
    OR link_title LIKE '%$s%' 
    OR tags LIKE '%$s%')
  AND post_status <> 'Initialized'
```

This way the query search the $s in one of the `post_status` and, if found, get all posts if the status is different from 'Initialized'

Using your code, instead return a false result, the query search for one of the likes but the last one (`tags`) is computed using the and.. `tags` AND `post_status`, so it will return all the posts where, title description etc matches the like but the status is irrelevant...

Comment: i'm using php and $ sign is parsed by php and it represents variable 's'.